# How to trigger custom event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, custom-events

I'm attaching a custom event handler to the `body` in jQuery's `ready` method.
Afterwards I immediately `trigger` the custom event but nothing seems to happen.

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("test", function(){ alert("test triggered"); }
    $("body").trigger("test");
}
```

Comment: .on - Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. what is the event here?

Comment: @dementic please don't change the code in edits

Comment: @zod "test", it's a custom event.

Comment: rolled question back to original state to reflect the root problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you **have a syntax error**

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("test", function(){
        alert("test triggered");
    });  < ---- Missing this
    $("body").trigger("test");
});
```

Secondly you cannot trigger the event from the console , as `$(function() {});` **forms a closure** and you will not have access to any of the methods inside them

For it to work like you are expecting , put a debug point in your script file and then try to trigger the event. It works now as the events are in scope.

Comment: Sure you can. Executing `$("body").trigger("test");` in the console will work. Why wouldn't it work? `$` is a global variable.

Comment: My apologies on the syntax error. Didn't know that an event listener wouldn't hear an event happening outside of its closure. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your code is not formatted correctly. Check your debug console to confirm.

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("test", function(){
        alert("test triggered");
    });
    $("body").trigger("test");
}
```